# OpenVPN connection Error: Connection activation failed: Could not find source connection

Tags: networking, vpn

This relates to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

The XFCE4 GUI desktop environment is installed.

After the upgrade from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS, my VPN connections, previously working, no longer work. I have set up PPTP and OpenVPN connections.

The netplan configuration is

```
ethernets:
    enp1s0:
        addresses: []
        dhcp4: true
version: 2
```

Please note that I have pretty much exhausted everything I can find on the internet about the topic, but my knowledge & expertise in networking at this level is limited.

Using the desktop nm-applet the VPN connection items are greyed out. Starting nm-applet with sudo the items seem active but don't respond.

I have resorted to nmcli.

```
nmcli con gives me

myOpenVPN      9439b05e-bc7e-419b-8679-95aa84394af2  vpn       --
```

I note the device column is empty. Should it be?

Attempting

```
sudo nmcli c up myOpenVPN
```

gives me

Error: Connection activation failed: Could not find source connection.

**/var/log/openvpn** is empty

```
grep VPN /var/log/syslog
```

gives me

> /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/myOpenVPN
>   (9439b05e-bc7e-419b-8679-95aa84394af2,"myOpenVPN") Jun 15 14:55:21
>   mythserver02 NetworkManager[1961]:   [1560576321.7239] audit:
>   op="connection-activate" uuid="9439b05e-bc7e-419b-8679-95aa84394af2"
>   name="myOpenVPN" pid=19429 uid=0 result="fail" reason="Could not find
>   source connection.

"

```
journalctl -u NetworkManager.service
```

> Jun 15 14:51:44 mythserver02 NetworkManager[1961]:  
>   [1560576104.9623] error requesting auth for
>   org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.reload: Authorization check failed:
>   Failed to open file “/proc/19299/status”: No such file or directory
>   Jun 15 14:51:44 mythserver02 NetworkManager[1961]:  
>   [1560576104.9629] error requesting auth for
>   org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.checkpoint-rollback: Authorization
>   check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/19299/status”: No such file
>   or directory Jun 15 14:51:44 mythserver02 NetworkManager[1961]: 
>   [1560576104.9635] error requesting auth for
>   org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-statistics:
>   Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/19299/status”:
>   No such file or directory Jun 15 14:51:44 mythserver02
>   NetworkManager[1961]:   [1560576104.9640] error requesting auth
>   for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-connectivity-check:
>   Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/19299/status”:
>   No such file or directory Jun 15 14:55:21 mythserver02
>   NetworkManager[1961]:   [1560576321.7239] audit:
>   op="connection-activate" uuid="9439b05e-bc7e-419b-8679-95aa84394af2"
>   name="myOPenVPN" pid=19429 uid=0 result="fail" reason="Could not find
>   source connection."

There is no /proc/19222 - what is that?

Any help. anyone?

Thanks

Comment: I am seeing the same thing on my 18.04 system - any luck?